# Строки и функции работы с ними (задание)

Tags: c, строки, функции

Необходимо ввести строку произвольной размерности, содержащую английские слова, разделённые любым количеством пробелов между собой. Выполнить сортировку слов по алфавиту и вывести готовый вариант на экран (с использованием прототипов своих функций и их реализацией). Я написал идею своего кода, но она нерабочая - программа обрывается на цикле с strcmp:

if (strcmp(*(s+i), *(s+j)) < 0)

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

char* vvod_str(int* len) 
{
    *len = 0;
    int cap = 1;
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); 
    char c = getchar(); 
    while (c != '\n') {
        s[(*len)++] = c; 
        if (*len >= cap) {
            cap *= 2; 
            s = (char*)realloc(s, cap * sizeof(char));  
        }
        c = getchar();          
    }
    s[*len] = '\0'; 
    return s; 
}

void sort_words(char** s, int n)
{
    char* x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(*(s+i), *(s+j)) < 0)
            {
                x = *(s+j);
                *(s + j) = *(s + i);
                *(s + i) = x;
            }
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
        int n;
        printf("Enter string: ");
        char* s = vvod_str(&n);
        sort_words(&s, n);
        printf("Sort string: ");
        puts(s);
        free(s);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит обрывается?

Answer (score 0):

я может что-то путаю, но я вижу

1. ввод строки посимвольно
2. попытку отсортировать массив строк

а вот разбитие введенной строки на массив слов я не вижу

в итоге у вас происходит следующее:

1. когда вводится строка вы определяете ее длину (кол-во символов) - `len`
2. строка у вас одна, но `n` - кол-во слов у вас указано от `len` - кол-во символов
3. и когда выполняется

вот этот код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(*(s+i), *(s+j)) < 0)
```

вы сравниваете не строки, вы интерпретируете `char*` (строку) как `char**` (массив строк) и пытаетесь сравнивать несколько строк

`n > 1` (длина начальной строки), то происходит вход в двойной цикл и
из строки вы получаете по 4 байта строки которые интерпретируете как указатели!!!

в итоге на выходе левые указатели на левые данные, сравнение которых приводит к ошибке